# What is the appropiate way to create a globally accessible object in C++

Tags: c++

Here is the thing. I have a class that functions as a log writer. I would like to create an instance of this class that can be seen by every other class in my program.

How can I do this?

Comment: Some people might deny it but that would be a singleton.

Comment: @VTT not saying you are not right, but globals/singletons are just *so much* pain waiting to happen - it makes me sad.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I kindly decline singleton battle challenge by stating that implementing a singleton pattern is just a rational way of avoiding overhead of passing / storing references to a commonly used object everywhere.

Comment: @VTT let's leave it at that.

Comment: `std::cout` is an example of _this very thing_.

Comment: @VTT: singleton offers global access, but also only one instance of the class. OP doesn't state that other instance should be avoided.